# React-navigation: How to add navigation that doesn't show up in TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm getting started with expo which uses react-navigation.
im playing around with building off the default TabNavigation app.
By default it has a RootStackNavigator which loads a MainTabNavigator

```
const RootStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MainTabNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'normal',
      },
    }),
  }
);
```

The MainTabNavigator is a TabNavigator instance.

I've created a screen "ListItemScreen" and added it to the TabNavigator.
On this screen I want a button that goes to another screen "FormScreen" with a form for adding an item.
How do I create the for "FormScreen" without adding it to the TabNavigator?
Am I supposed to create a StackRouter? If so, how do i structure the files?
I've read the docs several times but not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add `FormScreen` into `TabNavigator`, add to `StackNavigator` instead.

```js
const RootStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    FormScreen: {
      screen: FormScreen,
    },
    /* ... other routes ... */
  }
}
```

So the `Button` within Tabs can call `navigate()` directly:

```js
<Button title="Go FormScreen" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('FormScreen')} />
```

Offical document [Nesting a Navigator in a Screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting#Nesting-a-Navigator-in-a-screen) gives a great example for this.

Comment: Thanks. I totally skipped that section I guess. I thought "nested navigation" was something more advanced that I didn't need.